# How to protect metadata in a office file which was generating by java?

Tags: java, excel, file, properties, metadata

I have a issue, but i cannot find out a way to resolve it:
I generate a word file or a excel file using java code. But i don't know how to protect its metadata.

I do right click on the file, choose Properties, choose Details to view metadata. At there, everyone can Remove Properties, Add, Edit, Delete value of Title, Subject, Categories, Authors, Company, ...
I dont't know how to lock value fileds, set password or any ... so that noone can Remove Properties, Add, Edit, Delete value of Title, Subject, Categories, Authors, Company, ...

The code for generating i'm using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
        Excel();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

public static void Excel() throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");

    Object[][] bookData = {
            {"Head First Java", "Kathy Serria", 79},
            {"Effective Java", "Joshua Bloch", 36},
            {"Clean Code", "Robert martin", 42},
            {"Thinking in Java", "Bruce Eckel", 35},
    };

    int rowCount = 0;

    for (Object[] aBook : bookData) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);

        int columnCount = 0;

        for (Object field : aBook) {
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(++columnCount);
            if (field instanceof String) {
                cell.setCellValue((String) field);
            } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
            }
        }

    }

    POIXMLProperties prop = workbook.getProperties();
    POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProp = prop.getCoreProperties();
    coreProp.setCreator("reu");
    coreProp.setCategory("reu title");
    PackagePropertiesPart ctProp = coreProp.getUnderlyingProperties();


    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Working\\TProjects\\MetaSecu\\JavaBooks.xlsx")) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
    }
}
```

-> Could you please help me to give some ways to resolve this issue?